# upgrading react-native from 0.50.4 to 0.60.0 using rn-diff-purge

Tags: react-native

**Build failed with**: Could not find method enabled() for arguments [[]] on task ':app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec

Comment: Did you find any solition?